# How to setText on TextView in widget?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-appwidget

in my application i want to "setText" to TextView after i clicked button. but the widget crashes! and the text not change i know for sure that my button click it's working fine. but still when i tried to running the "setSomeText();" method the application crashing.
I think the reason it's because i'm not doing it inside the "OnUpdate" Override method.
here is my code :

```
public class WidgetClock extends AppWidgetProvider{


    public   RemoteViews views;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {


        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_clock);

            Intent intent = new Intent("enterAction").addCategory("enterAction");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bEnter_Widget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println("action:" + action);

        if ("enterAction".equals(action)) {

            System.out.println("views = " + views);
        if(views != null){
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.txWorkName_widget, "Works!");

        }

        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);

        }
    }


}
```

**I getting the "views" as null.**

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: your views is null when onRecieve() call, so please manage your code so that views will initialize when onRecieve call.

Comment: use views static and public then check, may be it will work.

Comment: I know that if i using `views.setTextViewText(R.id.txOnCLock_Widget);` on the "onUpdate" it works. but how to handle that not in the"onUpdate" method?

Comment: Check if `views==null` first. If not null then only do your work.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 ok, now it's not crashing. but no result too on the textView

Comment: You will have to debug why its null where you think it shouldn't be. I can't do that when I don't have the code.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you are right my views is null but why?

Comment: I don't think using `views` in `onReceive` is right.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 so, i need to call 'onUpdate' manually?